# How to include a whole html file to another in thymeleaf, not only a specific div?

Tags: thymeleaf

I have two html files, one contains a navbar and a sidebar. I would like to include that to another html file using thymeleaf.

Now I use jquery, the following way:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
      $("#includedCommonParts").load("/common_webpage_parts.html");
    });
    </script>
...
<div id="includedCommonParts"></div>
```

So I need the two html files merged to one, using only thymeleaf. I cannot use php, and I shouldn't use jquery either.

My file structure is the following:

```
├───public
│       common_webpage_parts.html
│       jquery.js
│       main.js
│
└───templates
        login.html
        users.html
```

The common_webpage_parts.html should be included in `users.html`

The `common_webpage_parts.html` contains multiple divs and css tags in `<style>` tags, so I don't want to include divs one-by-one.

This is a spring project by the way.

Thank you!

Comment: For this, I think you should look up Thymeleaf's 'Layout Dialect' -- https://ultraq.github.io/thymeleaf-layout-dialect/ -- I think it's great for stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally use thymeleaf layout dialect as Metroids commented: [thymeleaf layout dialect](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html), **chapter 4**. This is the best solution to avoid duplicated work in every file (which is prone to error) and to achieve cleanliness.

Alternatively (for example once I couldn't add the layout dialect library due to project restrictions), you can place each common part in the common_webpage_parts.html file inside `<th:fragment>` tags and load them with `<th:include>` or `<th:replace>` in your other html files wherever you need them. You can look at this is done in [thymeleaf standard layouts](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html), **chapter 3**.